# Html/Javascript stepper - Go back to the first step on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My stepper code is as follow:

```
<div id="stepp" class="step">
  </br></br></br>
    <md-card ng-init="step2.disabled = true; step3.disabled = true; selected = 0">
      <md-steppers  md-selected="selected" md-stretch-steppers="always">
        <md-step label="Lab1" md-complete="step1.completed"> 
          <md-content>
            <iframe id="iframe0" name="myIframe0" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
            <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1; step1.completed=true; step2.disabled = false">NEXT</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-step>
        <md-step label="Lab2" md-complete="step2.completed" ng-disabled="step2.disabled">
          <md-content>
            <iframe id="iframe1" name="myIframe1" frameborder="5" width="1500" height="1500"></iframe>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 0">PREV</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 2; step2.completed=true; step3.disabled=false">NEXT</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-step>
        <md-step label="End" md-complete="step3.completed" ng-disabled="step3.disabled">
          <md-content>
            <h1>
            All done!
            </h1>
            <h5> </br> You have completed this training path. </br> You can go back through the labs or select another training.
            </h5>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="selected = 1">PREV</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-step>
      </md-steppers>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to ensure that if for example you click somewhere you can return to the initial state even if you have gone on with the various steps?

*Obviously* a different solution from adding another button inside the html. I need some javascript code to insert into a .js file.

Comment: `example you click somewhere you can return to the initial state` -- Click where?

Comment: i have a graph with various nodes and when i click on a node the stepper start

Comment: Can you create a working sample on `stackblitz`? it hard to help without working sample